# Multiple ssl certificates / ip addresses on an single GCE instance

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine

I have 3 virtual hosts running on my GCE instance and they all require SSL. I can't figure out how to add extra IP address to my instance in order to allow multiple ssl enabled vhosts (apache). The docs say i can do it using protocal forwarding, but im a bit of a GCE novice and cant seem to get it to work. This was pretty straight forward in amazon AWS.

Has anyone done this before? (I do not want to use SNI as we still have some xp users out there)

Thanks

Max

Comment: You need to setup a HTTPS load balancer for that https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/, the SSL certificate will be attached to the load balancer. Create multiple forwarding rules to map multiple external IPs to the same instance.

Comment: thanks Dagang ... that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a HTTPS load balancer for that https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http, the SSL certificate will be attached to the load balancer. Create multiple forwarding rules to map multiple external IPs to the same instance.

Comment: Thanks Dagang .. I did try to accept your answer but i do not have enough reputation to vote on answers - i will come back and accept when i am more reputable.